Call PL/SQL from JDBC has different behaviour with OracleConnection and Connection
I need to change package variable using JDBC and get new value back.
Oracle package:
    create or replace package test_pkg
    as
       test_num number := 10;
    end;

When I do it via java.sql.Connection, it returns new value of variable:
    BigDecimal newValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(345);
    
    try (Connection conn = JDBCDataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call test_pkg.test_num := ? }")) {
            stmt.setBigDecimal(1, newValue);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }
    }

    BigDecimal retVal;
    
    try (Connection conn = JDBCDataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call test_pkg.test_num}")) {
            stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DECIMAL);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            retVal = stmt.getBigDecimal(1);
            
        }
    }

    System.out.println(retVal);

Output: 345
But if unwrap java.sql.Connection to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection using conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class)
then it returns original value, not the new one.
        BigDecimal newValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(345);
    
    try (OracleConnection conn = JDBCDataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class)) {
        try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call test_pkg.test_num := ? }")) {
            stmt.setBigDecimal(1, newValue);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }
    }

    BigDecimal retVal;
    
    try (OracleConnection conn = JDBCDataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class)) {
        try (CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call test_pkg.test_num}")) {
            stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DECIMAL);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            retVal = stmt.getBigDecimal(1);
            
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(retVal);

Output: 10
I need to understand why it works in such way with OracleConnection and how to resolve it.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE PACKAGE and CREATE PACKAGE BODY statements; the Java code for both the wrapped and unwrapped connections; and the output from both your snippets of code.

A package variable is effectively a global variable. Are you sure that no other session has set the value (or recompiled the package) between you making the first call to set the value and the second call to get the value?

What is an original value? How did you test it? It is a wrong syntax for call statement, the variable didn't set.

@RomanC Presumably it is a default value provided in the CREATE PACKAGE code fiddle - which is why I asked the OP for a complete [MRE].

@MT0 done. Both cases are absolutly same, there is no other session, I just change type of Connection object

You called twice unwrap(): are you sure you don't get 2 different instances?
